# What is the Fastest and Easiest Way to Upgrade Magento's Database?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, upgrade

Specifically I need to upgrade from version 1.9.11 to 1.11.20. I have all the changes made in the code, I just need to some how upgrade the databases (which may even be compatible out of the box).

I know there is upgrade scripts in each core module's directory, however is there a way to run all upgrades at once. I would prefer not to go to each of the core modules and have to run the scripts separately.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The database upgrade scripts are run automatically the first time you access your website after a code upgrade. The code version is kept in the database and checked on every request. If a code upgrade is detected Magento will execute all database update scripts starting from the previous code version. In theory this should work and for small upgrades it does. But be careful when doing major version upgrades.

Comment: They are automatically loaded any time the Magento page is loaded.  You should look at the class `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();`

Comment: I just did an upgrade of CE 1.4.2 -> 1.6.2 and our DB is 2.7G in size. You might find it necessary to increase your `php_value memory_limit` to something like 1024M and `php_value max_execution_time` to a huge number, like 45000. That's what I did and it is working ok. For my hosting setup, these values are set in the `.htaccess` file.